# How to create new array from existing array inside SwiftUI View Init

Tags: arrays, swift, swiftui

In the following code, I'm trying to create an array called `recordsPlusOne` with all items from an array inside the `recordsViewModel` (`recordsViewModel.records`) and one new record that needs to be created inside the `RecordsView` but I'm getting errors when I call `recordsViewModel.records` inside the `init()`

How can I create a new array with all items from an existing one plus one record that needs to be created inside the `init()` of the `RecordsView`?

### Code:

```
struct RecordsView: View {
    @ObservedObject var recordsViewModel: RecordsViewModel
    private var recordsPlusOne: [Record] = []
    
    init(){
        let newRecord = Record()
        recordsPlusOne = recordsViewModel.records // thows error 1
        recordsPlusOne.append(newRecord)
    }// thows error 2

    var body: some View {
       // some code to display the records
    }
}
```

### Error 1

> Variable 'self.recordsViewModel' used before being initialized

### Error 2

> Return from initializer without initializing all stored properties

Comment: `recordsViewModel: RecordsViewModel` needs an initial value. and SwiftUI wrappers like `@StateObject` and `@EnvironmentObject` are not available on `init`

Comment: So, what I'm trying to accomplish is not possible? Thanks

Comment: It is, if an initial value is coming from the parent view or being created before that line in the init. As of right now the initial value doesn't exist, anywhere.

Comment: In my case, it's coming from a parent view. What would you suggest as the solution? Thanks!

Comment: Pass it as an argument in the init

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to do if `recordsViewModel` will be injected via `init` arguments, like

```
init(vm: RecordsViewModel) {   // << here !!
    let newRecord = Record()
    recordsPlusOne = vm.records       // << pre-use !!
    recordsPlusOne.append(newRecord)
    recordsViewModel = vm                 // << initializing !!
}
```